# ordered field and R can embed

Tags: field-theory

errr.. Is there exists any field $\mathbb{F} \neq \mathbb{R} $ such that:

- ordered field
- $\mathbb{R}  \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{F}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the field of rational functions $\mathbb{R}(x)$, in which an element $\frac{a_nx^n +\cdots+ a_0}{b_m x^m + \cdots + b_0}$ is considered a positive element if and only if $\frac{a_n}{b_m}$ is positive as a real number.  You can verify that this satisfies all the properties of an ordered field, and $\mathbb{R}$ sits naturally inside it as a subfield.